# DataRowView -ASP.NET /C#

Tags: asp.net

What is the actual use of DataRowView in ASP.NET ? can you give a simple example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't part of ASP.NET, rather it's part of ADO.NET. MSDN has a good example of what it does [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowview.aspx), although it doesn't really say why you'd use it.

In a nutshell it lets you see the original or the modified view of a row that has been data-bound to a grid. You'd typically use it to do simple validation or implement a simplistic "undo".

In practice, as in an ASP.NET application you'd not persist edits directly except under your control, it doesn't really serve much function. It's more useful in Windows Forms.